# Good examples of projects with thoses priorities?

Tags: cost-management, prioritization, schedule, scope

To illustrate the iron triangle, I'm looking for general examples of projects with the following definitions of priorities at the beginning:

1. Scope -> Cost -> Schedule
2. Scope -> Schedule -> Cost

Many thanks for your help :)!

Comment: It is likely that any project could be prioritised in different ways, depending on the organisation's objectives for the project. The main point within the triangle is that any change to any of the vertices will have an impact on at least one of the others - and in most cases both of the others - and it is the organisation that determines which is the more significant. In my experience, it is almost impossible to change scope without changing BOTH cost and time, especially if the scope is increasing rather than decreasing.

Comment: "General examples" are better found by a search engine or other research. Questions on PMSE are generally expected to yield canonical answers, but your question is predicated on a set of *a priori* assumptions about prioritization that can't be defined or answered in a canonical way and don't reflect the underlying purpose of the theorem anyway. If you edit the question to be less of an opinion poll and more about a concrete set of examples, the community might re-open the question.

Answer (score 1):

The projects are not the issue. Determination of priority with those constraints is customer specific and those customers can have different priorities for different projects performed at different times for a whole host of dynamic, fluid, and chaotic factors.